# Can you identify these minifigures - sports, military and aliens

Tags: clone-brands, minifigure-identification

These have no marking on them. Does anyone know who made these and what set these are from?

[image: figures]

[image: figures]

[image: figures]

Answer (score 2):

The third figure is from a Best-lock Military set

[image]

I think the alien figures are from Make-It Blocks

a [Dollartree](https://www.dollartree.com/its-all-about-blocks/idea-20200204-1) brand
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first two definitely look like [Oyo](http://thebrickblogger.com/2015/02/oyo-sports-how-it-compares-to-lego/). The others are identified (with photographic evidence) by @Syberion as Best-Lock and Make-It Blocks.